# Plot hazard ratios by subgroups

Tags: r, cox-regression

I use the "lung" dataset of the survival package, which I added some columns to ("treatment", "age60").

Basically I calculated the HR for an event (death) depending on the treatment like this:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

dataset = lung
dataset$treatment <- round(runif(228, min = 0, max = 1))

dataset <- dataset %>% 
  mutate(age60 = case_when(
    age <= 60 ~ 0,
    age > 60 ~ 1))

model1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ treatment, data = dataset)
summary(model1)
```

Now I know, that treatment reduces the risk of dying (exp(coef) = 0.91).

So here are my questions:

1. In a next step I would like to analyze exactly this treatment effect in subgroups of the dataset, f.e. between males and females, between under and over 60 years of age or by another grouping variable "ph.ecog". **But I would like to calculate HRs for just treatment on death by always only ONE grouping variable**, f.e. treatment effect on death between males and females, or in another analysis treamtent effect on death between under and over 60 years.
2. These different (independent) HR I would like to show in a forest plot like this https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/survminer/reference/ggforest-2.png.
   In the first row I would like to show the overall HR of the treatment (independent from subgroup analysis, which I assume is model1) and below for every grouping variable like in the example (male/female, under/over 60 years, different types of "ph.ecog") - so it should look like this (**the HRs are just random**):

sex > 0 > reference | sex > 1 > 1.34

age60 > 0 > reference | age60 > 1 > 3.48

ph.ecog > 0 > reference | ph.ecog > 1 > 2.70 | ph.ecog > 2 > 1.43 | ph.ecog > 3 > 4.92.

**The key information a reader of this plot should get is: What is the treatment effect of the drug (treament = 1) on dying (status = 2) in the different subgroups (male/female, age below or above 60, etc.).**

I hope I explained everything that is needed to answer my question.

Thank everyone for support!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this: Try `survivalAnalysis` package See here https://rdrr.io/cran/survivalAnalysis/man/forest_plot.html. You may need to adopt to your solution!

```
#install.packages("survivalAnalysis")
library(survivalAnalysis)
dataset %>% 
  analyse_multivariate(vars(time, status),
                       vars(treatment, sex, age, ph.ecog)) %>% 
  forest_plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you TarJae for your answer, but is the HR fox sex (0.58) the risk of dying under the use of treatment? As they are listet in the code equally (vars(treatment, sex, age, ph.ecog)) it seems to me that the first HR (0.98) is the risk of dying under treatment, the second HR (0.58) the risk of dying if sex = 1, the third HR (1.01) if age60 = 1 and so on. What I'm looking for is the HR for each characteristic of a variable - I edited my post to illustrate this (the bold formatted part in the end of the post).

Comment: Yes! this is a multivariate analysis. A multivariate cox proportional analysis is not trivial. Usually you first start with a log rank and get one HR for each variable and similtanously test of THIS variable and check for significance. Then you decide the cut off of your p-value to enter to the multivariate cox analysis. You must have knowledge about the assumption of a cox regression analysis. There are several sites and tutorials on the internet. My example is a suggestion. You can take out one variable and see that the HR will change for all.

Comment: HR will always change if you alter the variables in the model. But this is the strength of a multivariate analysis and it is more the real situation as the assessment of only one variable. ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But is there a way to show all characteristics of a variable in the plot? I mean the HR for sex = 0 and sex = 1, age60 = 0 and age60 = 1, ph.ecog = 0 and ph.ecog = 1 and ph.ecog = 2 and ph.ecog = 3? Do you know what I mean? Or does this idea not make sense? In my idea I then could say that the risk of dying under treatment is 0.58 among males and f.e. 0.42 for females...