# analyse_multivariate > Object xyz not found

Tags: r, cox-regression

I asked for the solution a problem, which was solved by a user in this post: [Plot hazard ratios by subgroups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531908/plot-hazard-ratios-by-subgroups). I also found this vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survivalAnalysis/vignettes/multivariate.html (first code block) on the same issue. I went through this tutorial and everything works fine on my computer - I get the same results like in the example.

Now I tried to apply this method on my data (just changed the name of the data frame and the variable names) but since hours it is not possible for me to do that because I get the following error: **Error in eval(variables_names, envir = envir, enclos = baseenv()): object 'Age' not found**.

I use this code:

```
mydata %>%
  analyse_multivariate(vars(time, died),
  covariates = vars(Age, Gender, Insufficiency)) ->
result
```

If I run this, I get the error mentioned above, but if I run mydata$Age in the next line, I get all values of Age displayed without any issue. The same with Gender and Insufficiency - so the data does exist.

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong with my code?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show a `dput()` or `dput(head())` of your data `mydata`.

Comment: Hi Martin Gal! Thank you for your answer. As this is not my data I am not allowed to post (also not part of) this data.
But I compared the dput(head()) of mydata with the output of this function from the examples I related to and the only difference is that class(mydata) gives back two types: "matchdata" "data.frame" (so it seems that there are two classes, whereas in the example data in the tutorials it's only "data.frame". Could this be the reason?

Comment: This *could* be the reason, but I doubt it. It's nearly impossible to answer the question without the data used. Are you able to make a small example that causes the same problem by replacing your real data with some random data?

Comment: I know that it is really hard to answer such question without the data set (I'm really sorry for that). I try to reproduce this error in a random dataset. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`covariate_name_dict` is missing, thats why it is showing the error.

Try the code below

```r
covariate_names <- c(Age="Age", Gender="Gender", Insufficiency="Insufficiency")

mydata %>%
  analyse_multivariate(vars(time, died),
  covariates = vars(Age, Gender, Insufficiency)),
  covariate_dict_name = covariate_names ->
result
```

Comment: I guess, the `)` aren't placed correctly.